# On which site should I ask this question on time/senses? Is there evidence that we have more than 5 senses?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The concept of time is fascinating. An aspect of time that I have been thinking about is how do we experience time? We have always been taught that we have 5 primary senses, but none of them can detect the passage of time. However, all of us can tell the difference between 5 minutes and 50 minutes without any kind of external stimulus. Is this evidence that we have more than just 5 senses?

I think this question may be difficult without first understanding the fundamental nature of time -- and I do not, but it certainly is interesting to consider.

Comment: I have a 'craposcope' sense.  I can tell, with almost 100% accuracy, when I am going to down and close vote a question, even before I open it and start to read.  Just a glance at the title of a bad question is enough.

Comment: Not every question has a home on Stack Exchange.

Comment: and you both may well be right.

Comment: So I decided not to ask this on SE, do I accept the answer, delete the question, or let it ride?

Answer (score 3):

[Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) has a number of questions about [human senses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensation+human-biology), but this question feels almost philosophical to me.

I found [an answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/32531/14245) on [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) which sort-of deals with this topic, at least with the connection between senses and time.

Be sure to read their [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking questions there, though.

Comment: Cognitive Sciences also seems like a likely target. They have a [time](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag, with at least [one question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5180) that seems to ask this fairly well, so definitely check for dupes first.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't thought of that. You should post it as a separate answer, it's definitely good.

Comment: @Geobits I will try reading there.